# how to select exact json value in mysql query condition

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to select exact json value in mysql query condition, currently i am using LIKE and it work but like returns false positive.

my code is::

```
$id='1';
```

json data example:: `["1","12","38"]`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `json_column` LIKE '%".$id."%' ";
```

with this query, it returns both 1 and 12. how can i get just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the extra quotes:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE json_column LIKE '%\"$id\"%'";
```

However, this is wide open to SQL inject if `$id` comes from user input. Be careful.

The more secure method would be to use parameterised queries with PHPs [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) as follows:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE json_column LIKE '%\"?\"%'");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
```

Comment: hey, this does not return specific data. it basically return all rows. :(

Comment: btw, the id does come from the user side but the database account does not have admin rights so i dont think one can cause harm

Comment: The current solution is a security risk then. Check this comic example of how it could be exploited https://xkcd.com/327/. I would highly recommend looking into SQL injection prevention http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php (example 4 is particularly relevant).

Comment: thank you for the advise. what if i escape all $_GET and $_POST with mysql_real_escape_string. wont that prevent the attack?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the method I would use. I don't have much experience with `mysql_real_escape_string()` unfortunately so I'd prefer not to comment.